# RASA X The path 'config.yml' does not exist. Please make sure to use the default location ('config.yml') or specify it with '--config'

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa, rasa-x

i was trying to integrate rasa to google assistant: https://blog.rasa.com/going-beyond-hey-google-building-a-rasa-powered-google-assistant/

Then after rasa train, I get this error

```
(voice_bot) arjun@arjun-Lenovo-ideapad:~/Desktop/rasa_google$ rasa train
/home/arjun/enviro/voice_bot/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:526: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/arjun/enviro/voice_bot/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:527: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/arjun/enviro/voice_bot/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:528: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/arjun/enviro/voice_bot/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:529: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/arjun/enviro/voice_bot/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:530: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/arjun/enviro/voice_bot/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:535: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
The path 'config.yml' does not exist. Please make sure to use the default location ('config.yml') or specify it with '--config'.
```

These are my versions:

- rasa (1.1.8)
- rasa-core (0.14.5)
- rasa-core-sdk (0.14.0)
- rasa-nlu (0.15.1)
- rasa-sdk (1.1.1)
- rasa-x (0.20.0)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Is config.yml in the same directory as your executable? If it is in a separate cfg directory, or if you are running my_script from another directory, you may have to say "my_script.py \configs\config.yml" ... you can also use os.chdir(dir_of_config.yml).

Comment: @aschultz thank you... i had my config.yml in other directory.. i changed it to my exectable...now its working

Comment: how did you change dir as executable ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to run

```
rasa init
```

This will take care of setting up your working directory

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the current working directory hasn't been selected. Use cd  to select the working environment. For example: `cd C:\Users\Jinu Augustine\Documents\rasabot`. Try `rasa train nlu` after this, it should work.